# Configure two loggers in Flask

Tags: python, logging, flask

In a Flask application, I would like to configure two differents file loggers:

- One for HTTP access logs (`access.log`), which will log stuff like:

  ```
  1.2.3.4 - [11/Jun/2018 09:51:13] "GET /some/path HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  ```
- One for application logs (`my_app.log`), which will keep logs defined by me in my code when I'm using `current_app.logger.info('some message')`:

  ```
  2018-06-08 15:08:50,083 - flask.app - INFO - some message
  ```

How should my configuration looks like to achieve this ? Here is what I tried, without success:

```
# content of "run.py" :
app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)

# Define 'my_app.log' :
handler = logging.FileHandler('my_app.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter(app.config['LOGGING_FORMAT'])
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)

# Define 'access.log' :
access_handler = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
access_handler = logging.FileHandler('access.log')
access_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
access_handler.setFormatter(app.config['LOGGING_FORMAT'])
app.logger.addHandler(access_handler)

# Then register my blueprints:
app.register_blueprint(some_blueprint, url_prefix='/')
....
```

And I run it with `python3 run.py`. With this config, the only logged stuff are the HTTP access logs in the `my_app.log` file.

What's wrong with my config ?

Comment: How do you launch your application? What's your current behavior?

Comment: could you please elaborate a little bit about what happens when you run the application?

Comment: I edited my question with the current behavior and the way I start my app